# Android Galaxy S6 AudioRecord not initialized

Tags: android, galaxy, audiorecord

Im trying to record speech using AudioRecord object.
It works great on all devices except Galaxy S6 edge.
Here the code

```
AudioRecord recorder = null;
                int desiredRate = 0;
                for (int rate : new int[] {44100, 8000, 11025, 16000, 22050}) {
                    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                    if (bufferSize > 0) {
                        // buffer size is valid, Sample rate supported
                        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

                        if (recorder.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                            recorder.release();
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

In the Galaxy the state is 0.
What can be the reason for it?